# FB PHP SDK : Can get public details in Localhost but not in Live Server

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This code displays complete FB details in localhost but only display id and name in live server.

```
if ($session){ //if we have the FB session
     //get user data
     $user_profile = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me'));

     $response = $user_profile->execute();
     $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

     // print data
     echo  print_r( $graphObject, 1 );
}
```

Sample Localhost output (Complete Public Details):

```
Facebook\GraphObject Object ( [backingData:protected] => Array ( [id] => 101 [email] => myEmail@gmail.com [first_name] => MyFname [gender] => male [last_name] => MyLName[link] => https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/101/ [locale] => en_US [name] => MyFname MyLname [timezone] => 4 [updated_time] => 2015-05-18T05:51:40+0000 [verified] => 1 ) )
```

Sample Live Server Output (Fb Id and Fullname *only*):

```
Facebook\GraphObject Object ( [backingData:protected] => Array ( [name] => Name LastName [id] => 101 ) )
```

**Permission: All Set**

```
$required_scope     = 'public_profile, email';
```

Thanks for your help (IA).

Comment: Are you using 2 different App IDs for your Localhost version versus your Live version? This sounds like this may be the case and that your Live server version is using v2.4 of the Graph API which implements 'declarative fields' meaning you need to specify the fields you wish to request. See here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

Comment: Hi @The1Fitz! Yes I am using two different (APP ID & APP Secret) in my Db_connect.php. E.g., $local = 1; if($local) { /* local connection */ } else { /*live server connection */} Do you think this kind of approach raised the issue? THanks!

Comment: Yup this is it more that likely. If you look at the application dashboard for your live server app ID you can see what version that app is. If it is v2.4 you will need to request the specific fields you want. I would also recommend considering using "Test Apps" as described here for your purpose: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps

Comment: @The1Fitz Thanks! V 2.3 and 2.4 differences. That fixed the issue. I probably have to refactor my code too :) thanks